# Why is cohere function in matplotlib (python) give answer different from mscohere function in MATLAB?

Tags: python, matlab, matplotlib

in maltlab and pythonmatplotlib.mlab contains Numerical python functions written for compatability with MATLAB commands with the same names.

1. But for me I get different results in MATLAB and python. Does anyone has any idea, why is it so?
2. MATLAB mscohere function has a parameter WINDOW to set the size of the window, which I do not find for cohere function in matplotlib.mlab (python)

   Cxy = mscohere(y1,y2,16,0,16)

   Cxy = matplotlib.pyplot.cohere(y1, y2,NFFT=16,noverlap=0)

where y1 and y2 are same in MATLAB and python and of length 1024

Any help?

Here is the code:

MATLAB:

```
Fs=8000;
y1=zeros(1,1024);
y2=zeros(1,1024);
for f =0:100:1900
    for n=0:1023
      y1(n+1)=y1(n+1)+sin(2*pi*f*n/Fs);
      if mod(f,200)==0
          y2(n+1)=y2(n+1)+sin(2*pi*f*n/Fs);
      end
    end
end

Cxy = mscohere(y1,y2,16,0,16);
display(Cxy);

Cxy =

    0.8300
    0.0504
    0.0006
    0.0082
    0.1828
    0.2562
    0.7984
    0.9788
    0.9884
```

PYTHON:

```
Fs=8000
sample=1024
frequencys=100 * np.arange(20)
#print(frequencys)

y1=np.zeros(sample)
y2=np.zeros(sample)
for f in range(frequencys.size):
    for n in range(sample):
        y1[n]=y1[n]+sin(2*pi*frequencys[f]*n/Fs)
        if frequencys[f]%200==0:
            y2[n]=y2[n]+sin(2*pi*frequencys[f]*n/Fs)
cxy,f = plt.cohere(y1, y2,NFFT=16,noverlap=0)
print(cxy)

    Cxy=[ 0.78894285  
0.06083255  
0.01161213  
0.00249976  
0.14194519  
0.38694284 
0.78120729  
0.8384586   
0.85438165]
```

Comment: Heads up: This question will be closed in not too long, because: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers." [Check this link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to see how you can improve the question and maybe get some good answers.

Comment: You need to provide example code that is able to fully reproduce the problem, as well as the real output and expected output.  Without knowing what y1 and y2 are, and without know what MATLAB and Python give you for Cxy, there is no way we can help you.

Comment: Both [matplotlib.mlab.cohere](http://matplotlib.org/1.2.1/api/mlab_api.html#matplotlib.mlab.cohere) and [matplotlib.pyplot.cohere](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.cohere) do have a parameter `window`.

Comment: @StewieGriffin Sorry. Added the actual code

Comment: @A.Donda window parameter in pyplot is just to set the window type. Not the size of the window

Comment: @user3852441, according to the documentation it is a vector. You can give the actual window coefficients, which determines type and size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Originally `matplotlib.mlab` functions were meant to provide similar capabilities to their MATLAB equivalents, but some basics approaches between MATLAB and numpy differ so they don't always do things in exactly the same way, and in some cases they have diverged somewhat due to differing needs and/or goals.  Nowadays `mlab` is more a set of numerical functions that aren't available in numpy but are needed by `matplotlib`.

In your case, the MATLAB function defaults to using a `hamming` window, while the `matplotlib` version defaults to using a `hanning` window.  You can reproduce the `MATLAB` results by simple passing an appropriately-lengthed `hamming` window.  Also, MATLAB uses `Fs=1` by default while matplotlib uses `Fs=2` by default, but I think that only changes the frequencies, not `cxy`:

```
>>> cxy, _ = mlab.cohere(y1, y2, window=np.hamming(16), NFFT=16, noverlap=0, Fs=1)
>>> print(cxy)
[  8.29985202e-01   5.03649611e-02   5.54167037e-04   8.19190824e-03   1.82760544e-01   2.56179777e-01   7.98391906e-01   9.78827021e-01   9.88429511e-01]
```

Comment: Thanks for d answer. It works. One more question "they don't always do things in exactly the same way" does that mean the use differnt logic or is it just the differnce in the parameter configurations?

Comment: Sometimes one, sometimes the other.  The `window` parameter in mlab takes a function or a vector, while in MATLAB it takes a vector or a length.  mlab's `specgram` gives the PSD by default but can be changed to a variety of types of STFT  (complex, magnitude, angle, or phase),  while MATLAB's uses the complex STFT or complex STFT and PSD depending on the outputs, with no other options.  mlab's `cohere` uses a default `Fs` of 2 while matlab uses 1.  In short, you can't just assume they are the same.  You really need to look at the documentation.