# Is there an analogue of a MATLAB function `mscohere` in Python?

Tags: python, matlab

In MATLAB have a function `mscohere` me it needs to be implemented in Python.
The MATLAB code is as follows:

```
[Cxy,~] = mscohere(LS,RS);
```

LS,RS - Arrays type float.

Do modules to the calculation of coherence? Or can anyone have expected it in Python?

[Documentation `mscohere` in MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/mscohere.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com)

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31829604/why-is-cohere-function-in-matplotlib-python-give-answer-different-from-mscoher) could be a good starting point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it has one in the scipy module:

```
scipy.signal.coherence(x, y, fs=1.0, window='hann', nperseg=256, noverlap=None, nfft=None, detrend='constant', axis=-1)
```

Detailed documentation with examples can be found [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.coherence.html)

Comment: But i use `matplotlib.mlab.cohere(x, y, NFFT=256, Fs=1)` http://matplotlib.org/api/mlab_api.html#matplotlib.mlab.cohere

Comment: though the response is also a working version, which I then returned :)